# TSQL: Update where count (select * from table) = 0

Tags: t-sql

I just want to know if this is possible
To select or update data, but only if another query returns zero results

so something like this

```
 Update A from tableA A
 Set A.value = 'test'
 where count(select * from tableB Where B.date = A.date) = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to write an `UPDATE` query with this logic.  You may use an `EXISTS` clause here:

```
UPDATE tableA a
SET value = 'test'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE a.date = b.date);
```

Comment: thanks, It had been so long since I used TSQL, that I forgot this command existed

Answer (score 1):

Probably this:

```
Update tableA
Set tableA.value = 'test'
where (select count(*) from tableB B Where B.date = tableA.date) = 0
```